# share record depend upon field value

Tags: apex, trigger, sharing, sharing-rule, owd

I have one custom object, in that one field named as 'status' - pick list value. my requirement is - when the status field goes to 'assigned',all profiles in org can able to see the record.if the pick list value is some other -none of the profile should see the record.how to achieve this.. In owd can we achieve this,how?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by Sharing Settings having rule on 'Based on criteria'. Select field as 'status' equals 'Assigned'. Share it with Public Group. You will have to create Public Group separately and all all users. Unfortunately, sharing cannot be done based on Profile.

[image]